# Trying to scan a vector of vehicles an extract information for lane switching C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to build a simulation which contains certain objects. I have vehicles and lanes. I have an engine which allows vehicles to advance, based on their velocity and acceleration.

```
bool Lane::allowedOvertake(double pos, double mindist)
{
    for (unsigned int iV = 0; iV < getNVehiclesinLane() - 1; iV++)
    {
        if ((fVehicles[iV]->getPosition() > pos - mindist)   // If inside rear safety distance.
            || fVehicles[iV]->getPosition() < pos + mindist) // If inside front safety distance.

        {}//continue
      //else {return false;}
    }
    return true;
}
```

I would like this `for` loop to scan over all the vehicles in a lane, so that a vehicle from a neighbouring lane can check whether it can move into this scanned lane. As a note, the `pos` and `mindist` parameters are the positions and the minimum distance the *lane seeking* vehicle needs to safely switch lanes. Also, `fVehicles` is a vector of vehicles. If the result is `true`, I then use an `if` statement in my 'master' object, the road, which allows for an actual switch to take place (using `vector.insert()`).

I currently get vehicles switching lanes without regard. At first glance, I would suspect it is the above function's logic which is incorrect. Any help in providing a fix, or even a better solution, would be appreciated.

Note: I have a vector of vehicles, and a vector of lanes. However, the vehicles are not ordered in the vector by their positions. I have been advised to re-design this so that the order of the vehicles in the vector are more significant and one can benefit from this when developing the code. However, for now, I would like to fix the design I currently have. Then I will look into redesigning the simulation to make the order more significant. Besides this, my problem above would still exist, just in a slightly different form.

Comment: To begin with, don't have that unconditional `return true` *inside* the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude, I'll make that change,

Comment: I have added more detail to explain what the `pos` and `mindist` parameters are. Apologies for not being clear

Comment: If you have to scan *all* the vehicles in a lane, the condition in the `for` loop should probably be `iV < getNVehiclesinLane()` or better, use a ranged loop.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, sorry. That shouldn't be `getNVehiclesinLane() - 1`. Earlier, I had an error, so made that change. Then I found this wasn't the error, but I forgot to undo the `- 1`. Thanks for that. Ranged-based loops are a good fix for exactly these types of silly mistakes.

Comment: Also, having a sorted by position vector, allows you to check if the *difference* between the positions of two consecutive cars is big enough to safely contain another car.

Comment: @Bob__ I understand, I will look into this later. However, is the logic of my loop correct? I'm worried it may be the cause for vehicles switching lanes without regard. I have made sure whatever I pass in for `double mindist` parameter is large, so vehicles shouldn't be going in if there isn't enough space to _safely_ move in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an unsorted `vector`, you have to check if all of them are distant enough from the passed position or, in other words, if [*none of*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) them is too close:

```
#include <algorithm>

bool Lane::allowedOvertake(double pos, double mindist)
{
    return std::none_of(
        fVehicles.begin(), fVehicles.end(), [pos, mindist] (auto & v) { 
            return v->getPosition() <= pos + mindist  
                   and  v->getPosition() >= pos - mindist;
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply. Do you mind giving an explanation of your answer? I am unfamiliar with this method.

Comment: Also, my vector of vehicles, fVehicles, is a one which contains pointers to vehicles. So, I guess I would just use `(auto v)` as one of the parameters for the `any_of` function.

Comment: @KarandeepGiddha From the reference: `std::any_of(first, last, p)` checks if unary predicate p (a [lambda expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) in this case) returns true for at least one element in the range [first, last). The lambda "captures" the values of `pos` and `mindist` and use them in the comparison with the actual element passed as argument. It returns true if the vehicle has an unsafe position, so `any_of` returns true as soon as at least one element of the vector is too close. You need the opposite value.

Comment: It's the same as having: `for (auto v : vehicles) { if ( is_too_close(v, pos, mindist) ) return false; } return true;`.

Comment: So, the reason why `!` has been used in `!std::any_of()` is to "reverse" the logic order for the one I require. Is that correct?

Comment: @KarandeepGiddha On second thoughts, you can simplify the logic (omitting the !) using the other library algorithm: `std::none_of`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Great, that definitely makes the logic less confusing. Thank You

Comment: I have tried to implement this, but I get a build error. The error is as follows: "invalid use of auto". Given my vector, fVehicles, contains pointers to vehicles, I did not use `(auto & v)`, but `(auto v)`. This causes the error I quoted above. Any help?

Comment: @KarandeepGiddha Use the exact type instead, the pointer to vehicle. The language has lambdas since C++11, but generic lambdas were introduced in C++14.